# Add lighting component inside custom component html tags

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I would like to know whether the following is possible.

I have created two custom lighting component called `menu` and `menu-item`

Can I use these two as follows.

```
<c-menu>
    <c-menu-item lable="item1"/>
    <c-menu-item lable="item2"/>
</c-menu>
```

I have seen some standard components use this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this with the help of [slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots).

In your template markup for the c-menu component you will leave an unnamed slot there as below

```
<template>
  <!-- all markups-->
 ---
  ---
   <slot> </slot>
</template>
```